# Is it possible to put a ios ad in a uitable cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to put a iOS ad in a `UITableCell`?

I believe it is possible in Xcode but does Apple accept it?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: @JoshCaswell If that's the case, why did 2 people bother making an answer for this then? Also, don't you think that your comment is a little unfair as this question talks about UITableViewCell and the answers are code based answers, so really it is a programming type question right?

Comment: @Dan The question reads "I believe it is physically possible in xcode but **does apple accept it**?" OP seems to know how; however, e can easily edit the question if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google admob to show adds within a tableviewcell.

There are two ways that ads can be implemented within Table View cells:

Only use one GADBannerView throughout the table. This would mean that the same ad is displayed in different cells in the table (preferred).
Leverage dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: so that GADBannerViews are created only when new cells are created.
Using one GADBannerView throughout the table does decrease ad diversity but generally increases the CTR for the ads that are shown because the user will more likely see the ads that are displayed. The example below will show how to implement this approach as it is the better practice.

Solution - Single GADBannerView Method 
For the purposes of this example, let’s assume that every 10th element in the list is going to be an ad. This means tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: will be set up with a conditional that modifies the placement of the GADBannerView for every tenth cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  int row = [indexPath row];

  // Assume that kFrequencyAdsInCells is 10 so every 10th row is an ad
  // Don't want first item to be an ad so use 10-1=9 instead of 0
  if ((row % kFrequencyAdsInCells) == (kFrequencyAdsInCells)) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Need to create a new cell object
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
                autorelease];
    }
    // If bannerView_ has a superview, then it has been added to a cell
    if (!bannerView_.superview) {
      // First ad request made, make the ad request and add it to this cell
      [self requestAd];     
    }
    // The banner will be removed from the other cell and put into here
    [cell.contentView addSubview:bannerView_];


}
…
```

Since ads are being inserted into the Table View now, any previous mapping to data in the model will be lost. Some quick math is necessary here to figure out how the rows in the Table View line up.

```
 // Complete in cellForRowAtIndexPath: if not ad

  // Make sure we get all of the items from our model
  row = row - floor((float)row/kFrequencyAdsInCells);

  cell.textLabel.text = [dataController_ objectInListAtIndex:row];
```

you can find more details over here [Embedding Google AdMob Ads Within A UITableView](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/03/embedding-google-admob-ads-within.html)

Comment: Nice answer but the OP did specifically ask for iAds, not Google AdMob adverts.